# Should I use Mann-Whitney U test, T-test, or something else?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, mean, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I have a problem where I experimentally want to see if a fall-time for a given a triangular pyramid differ compared to a square pyramid with the same cross-sectional area. Here is the data I have.

P3: 0.867 0.883 0.883 0.900 0.900 0.900 0.900 0.917 0.917 0.917 0.917 0.933 0.933 0.933 0.933 0.933 0.933 0.950 0.950 0.967

P4: 0.833 0.833 0.867 0.867 0.883 0.883 0.883 0.883 0.883 0.900 0.900 0.900 0.900 0.900 0.917 0.917 0.917 0.917 0.933 0.933

Note that the data is discreet, which is because the camera can only capture the time in steps of 1/60 seconds because the camera has 60 fps.

I started with a F-test (alfa=0.2) to see if the variances were different. I also assumed normality. [image: Results of the F-test.]

H0 could not be rejected, and the sample variances were therefore assumed to be equal.

Following this, the T-test was conducted when the sample variances are equal. [image: Here are the results of the T-test.]

The evidence that the means are unequal is strong according to me.

**Here's where I realized** that the data can be seen as ordinal, and that the Mann-Whitney U test use this type of data.

I just now did a quick two-tailed Mann-Whitney U test online with alfa=0.01 and it passed the test. The U-value was 100. The critical value of U at p<0.01 is 105. Therefore, the result is significant at p<0.01. It also passed the Mann-Whitney U test.

What do you think I should do given this data? Should I rely on one, the other, or both? Should I do something different?

Comment: Discrete does not imply *merely* ordinal: for your purposes, these fall times can be considered *continuous, ratio-level* measurements.  Your "paired variance" appears to be a *pooled* variance.

Comment: When you say "pyramid with three sides" are you talking about a tetrahedron (which name literally means '***four*** faces', not three!) -- or something else?

Comment: Updated the pyramid names; hopefully I got it right now!

Comment: @whuber Yes, it was a poor translation on my part :( The correct word is pooled variance! And thanks for the answer! I will look up this data type :)

Comment: 1) I have a couple of suggestions.  a) The two tests you are considering test different hypotheses.  Which hypothesis are you interested in?  b) When considering a parametric test (like the t test), it's useful to consider the conditional distribution of the data, either by having some understanding of the underlying nature of the data, or by examining the residuals of the analysis. Here, for each group, you could subtract the mean of that group from each observed value.  Then pool these residuals from the two groups, and plot a histogram of these pooled residuals.

Comment: 2) If you do that here, you'll get residuals that are fairly symmetric.